# I am going over the ne04j movie tutorial database and I want to output movie has the most number of actors in it?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, dbms-output

Which movie has the most number of actors in it?
Which pair of actors have acted together in most number of movies?

Here's what i tried

```
MATCH (actor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(movie:Movie) 
RETURN movie.name
```

I expect the movie name with a count of the number of actors in the movie

Comment: Start by doing a count and sort the result. Then get the topmost row using limit 1

Answer (score 0):

This will give you pairs of actors who have acted together in most number of movies. There are a lot of ties since 7 pairs have acted in 3 movies.

We get the max number of movies the actors acted together (3 movies).
Then again get the pair of actors where they acted in 3 movies.

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(n:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person) WHERE p1 > p2
WITH p1, p2, count(n) as movies 
WITH max(movies) as max_count ORDER by max_count DESC LIMIT 1
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(n:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person) WHERE p1 > p2
WITH max_count, p1, p2, count(n) as movies where movies  = max_count
RETURN p1 as Actor1, p2 as Actor2
```

It should be easy enough for you to do the other question about;

> Which movie has the most number of actors in it?